# Issues with .htaccess file

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I have 2 goals that I am trying to accomplish. 1st is to make sure the user is always using https and the 2nd is to get rid of .php extension entirely since every single one of my web page uses this.

My websites .htaccess file is wrong and I'm not entirely sure how to fix it. 
It redirects from urls such as:
www.mysite.com/login.php to www.mysite.com/mysite.com/login

The 2nd broken url manages to eliminate all the PHP but concats my entire website within itself...

I have tried other htaccess "php" file extension removers found on various sites but either they do not work or only partially work (only some of my web pages get the .php removed). I'm think I must be including one extra thing that is not needed in my .htaccess but I'm very unfamiliar with configuring this file so every time I make a change its straight to the 500 error page...

```
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31415926;includeSubDomains;"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# remove the .php extension 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# redirect from .php to less php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Enable the RewriteLog to understand how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

To remove .php from URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Your code is different from mine. I tested and it works normally. You will also need to change the links in the files.  `<a href="page.php"> Link </a>` to `<a href="page"> Link </a>`

Comment: This adds `.php` to the end of a url that does not contain it.  The removing takes place in creating the URL without the PHP extension.  (which is the correct way to do it).  But if you have a url that ends in `(.+)\.php$` then you need to redirect it to `$1 [R=301,L]` to remove it from the browser (or something like that).  Capture everything up to `.php` redirect it, then this rule (in the answer) will add `.php` back in for the server (it wont show in the URL)  The only way to change the URL in the browser is with a Redirect (well from server side at least).

Comment: lol i just assumed what you wrote @WelissonPereiraGomesdosSan was a PHP remover. I DO NOT want to add PHP back on. I'm trying to get pretty URL's

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix every single one of my urls ends with the extension PHP. I guess my question is what if everything is a POST request or simple redirection. Does capturing everything still work?

Comment: Everything should work correctly, but to remove the `.php` you have to redirect to the url without the .php, then you have to add .php back on (but only on the server)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#force HTTPs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# add the .php extension (so the server can process it)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  #is not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  #is not a file
#We don't want to add PHP to things like .js or .png or .php files.
#So if it's a real file we can stop here.
#If it's not just add .php
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]

# remove the .php extension and redirect to clean URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$  #ends in .php
RewriteRule (.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]
```

[Online Tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) - unfortunately I don't see a way to save the test.  It's a pretty nice tester, but it can't handle the `!-f` condition so keep that in mind.  Obviously some made up URL doesn't actually exist on the testers domain.

Anyway, when you put a URL like this:

```
www.example.com/somepage
```

The server cannot run that, what HTACESS does is behind the scenes it adds the `.php` extension and stops `L`.  So the URL the server sees is this `www.example.com/somepage.php`  Provided the URL doesn't exist as a real file or directory (before doing the rewrite rule).

However, when the URL is like this `www.example.com/somepage.php` then HTACCESS removes the `.php` and does a 301 `R=301` and stops `L`.  After the redirect the first rule will then add `.php` back into the URL but "Only" on the server so in the browser the url will not contain the PHP extension.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: so now I'm back to getting a 500 error again. So what you wrote out makes total sense to me. I do not not believe that I need to add a PHP extension on to anything. The way I designed my website is that everything uses the PHP extension including <a href> so it should always know that the file is a PHP file. I'm thinking that the redirection is wrong for my design at this point.

Comment: this is very bizarre indeed.... I do a big "no-no" on one of my webpages where it simply provides information. I do retain a PHP session on that webpage but other than that it does not pull from a database and could be written with an HTML extension yet even this page with the little amount of PHP it has can't seem to handle this redirect either